# Set optional username django User

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have to store Customer information in a Customer table. We don't need to store their `username` and `password`. But to create customer groups and users, I'm using django's `User` and `Group` Models. Here is the customer Model which I use to store it's basic information.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """
    The Customer 
    """
    UID = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=False)
    fk_details = models.ForeignKey(UserDetails, primary_key=False)
    fk_contact_details = models.ForeignKey(ContactDetails, primary_key=False)
    ...
```

This is a class method which creates user object for which later I'm using it to store customer information :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def create_user(self, req_dict):
    '''
    Create a new User 
    '''
    try:
        user=User.objects.create_user(**req_dict)
        user.save()
    except:
        return None
    return user
```

But this code is throwing an `IntegrityError` which is because we are not passing username in the `req_dict`

```
req_dict = {'first_name': u'John', 'last_name': u'Smith', 'email': u'john.smith@xyz.com'}
```

What's the way to store username optional while creating a new user?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @zanderle - What's the way to store username optional while creating a new user?

Comment: You should update your question and make that explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `django.contrib.auth` you can't make the username field optional. You always have to put a value in the database.

In order to bypass that, I suggest you generate a value in `create_user()` for username. You could either use a random value, or create a username from email. Just make sure that it's unique.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-save) to just provide default values

```
pre_save.connect(give_default_username, sender=User)
def give_default_username(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.username = 'default'
```

Any time a user object's save method is invoked, it will go through this method first to append your required values before continuing with the save method.

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of that signal.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @zanderle that it would be better to generate some username for your users. Maybe you can user their UID, or email, or something like this.

`pre_save signal` could solve your problem, but, as for me, it makes you system more implicit, because your models will be not consistent with your database.

Another way - to create some Default user for anonymous users. So, every db record will have user assignment and you will not force your customers to register.

Comment: Exactly, This is the reason I have asked the question.